# Layout in Next.js overshadows page content

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, layout

I am trying to use Bottom Navigation from material-ui (https://mui.com/material-ui/react-bottom-navigation/) as layout in my Next.js app.

However, the Navigation is overshadowing the bottom part of the page. I tried to change margins and paddings but it was of no use.

I am using the bottom navigation as exactly as Material-ui.

It looks like this without layout.

[image]

and with layout, it is overshadowing the content -

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: Could you give a code snippet or example screenshot? It is nearly impossible to help debug with the information given.

Comment: @LukeStorry added screenshots for reference

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell how you're using it without any provided code snippets, but it looks like the materialui navigation is designed to display over the top of the page content.

You need to add an empty `div` of the same height as the navigation just above the navigation in your layout so that it is pushed downwards by that amount.